# how can I accses the text contents of a specific DOM element stored in a array

Tags: javascript

I am building a task list generator for a Javascript course. And I am not sure how to get the value of a text node inside of a List item to compare it with the value of a input field in my filter function.

The logic is onkeyup call the function taskFilter.
In the function taskFilter set the const text = to the key pressed by the user.
grab all the dynamically generated li elements and store them in the const htmlCollecton.

Declare a new array called const htmlaray

loop through the html collection and convert it into a array.

loop through the created array htmlaray and compare the inputed text char with the inner text of the list item. And that is where I got stuck :(
I am new to javascript I may be doing this all wrong but I am not sure help would be greatly appreciated

THE HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <title>Task Generator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="mainContentContainer">
            <main class="mainContent">
                <span>
                    <h1 class="h1">Task List</h1>
                </span>
                <form class="form" action="" id="form">
                    <input type="text" name="taskInput" id="taskInput" placeholder="New Task"> <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add task" id="submitInput">
                </form>
                <section class="filterAndClearTasks">
                    <div class="secondInputField">
                        <input class="filterInput" type="text" name="filter" id="filter" placeholder="Filter Tasks">
                    </div>
                    <ul id="TaskCollection">

                    </ul>
                    <button id="clearTasks">Clear Tasks</button>
                </section>
            </main>
        </section>

        <script src="main.js">
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

THE CSS

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
  v2.0 | 20110126
  License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }

.mainContentContainer {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  padding: 1%; }

.mainContent {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.h1 {
  margin: 1rem 0rem 1rem 0.5rem; }

.form {
  margin: 0rem 0rem 1rem 0.5rem; }

#taskInput {
  width: 98%;
  border: #c8c1c1 2px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem; }

#submitInput {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 0.3rem 0rem 0.3rem 0rem; }

#submitInput:hover {
  background-color: #538a1c;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-color linear 0.5s;
  transition: background-color linear 0.5s; }

#filter {
  width: 98%;
  border: #c8c1c1 2px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem; }

.filterAndClearTasks {
  margin: 0rem 0rem 1rem 0.5rem; }

#TaskCollection {
  border: #c8c1c1 2px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 98%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 1%; }

.taskListItems {
  background: cadetblue;
  padding: 2%;
  border: black solid 2px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0.3rem 0rem 0.3rem 0rem;
  color: #242222;
  line-height: 1.3em; }

.taskListItems:hover {
  background: #265c5e;
  -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background-color linear 0.3s;
  transition: background-color linear 0.3s;
  color: #bdc6cd; }

.floatingBtn {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #0ee3cd;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.floatingBtn:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: whitesmoke;
  -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;
  transition: background-color linear 0.2s; }

#clearTasks {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  padding: 0.3rem 0rem 0.3rem 0rem; }

#clearTasks:hover {
  background-color: #191a18;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-color linear 0.5s;
  transition: background-color linear 0.5s; }
```

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    const taskCollection = document.getElementById("TaskCollection");
    const clearTaskButton = document.getElementById("clearTasks");
    const filterInput = document.getElementById("filter");
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput");


    function attachEventListeners() {
        form.addEventListener("submit", addtask);
        taskCollection.addEventListener("click", removetask);
        filterInput.addEventListener("keyup", taskFilter);
        clearTaskButton.addEventListener("click", clearAllTasks);

    } 
    attachEventListeners();

    function addtask(e) {
        const regexp = /^\s+$/;
        const task = taskInput.value;
        const result = regexp.test(taskInput.value);

        if (result === true || task === "") {
            alert("Please add a task!");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }else {
            console.log(result);
            const li = document.createElement("li");
            const button = document.createElement("button");
            const liText = document.createTextNode(task);
            const buttonText = document.createTextNode("x");

            li.appendChild(liText);
            li.className = "taskListItems clear";
            button.appendChild(buttonText);
            button.className = "floatingBtn";
            li.appendChild(button);
            taskCollection.appendChild(li);    
            taskInput.value = "";
            e.preventDefault();
            return true;
        }
    }

    function clearAllTasks() {
        while(taskCollection.firstChild) {
            taskCollection.removeChild(taskCollection.firstChild);
        }
    }

    function removetask(e) {
        if (e.target.className === "floatingBtn") {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this link?")) {
            e.target.parentElement.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    function taskFilter(e) {
        const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        const htmlCollecton = document.getElementsByClassName("taskListItems");
        const htmlaray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < htmlCollecton.length; i++) {
        htmlaray.push(htmlCollecton[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < htmlaray.length; i++) {
            if (text !== htmlaray[i].indexOf(innerText.toLowerCase()), 0) {
                htmlaray[i].style.display = "none";
            }else {
                htmlaray[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        console.log(htmlaray);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filters tasks:

```
for (var i = 0; i < htmlaray.length; i++) {
    if (htmlaray[i].innerText.indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        htmlaray[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
        htmlaray[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Is this the desired result? You can use `toLowerCase()` as you see fit--it might be appropriate to apply it to both the search string and the list item string.

Comment: Kind of, what I wanted it to do was take the value on the key up event which is converted to lowercase and compare it to the text inside the list items stored in the array. If they value on keyup matches the first text character inside the list item keep it displayed other wise hide it. I hope that makes sense :(

Comment: does `if (htmlaray[i].innerText[0] !== e.key.toLowerCase()) {` do the trick? This seems to do what you're asking, but the resulting behavior seems a little unintuitive to me.